# Scatter Plot of Large Datasets in Altair

Tags: python, dataframe, visualization, altair

I am attempting to use altair to illustrate correlation between historical RSI and 1-week returns for a fairly large dataset (~38k rows). I have already disabled max rows and am attempting to use altair data server. I have created a matplotlib plot, attached, that shows roughly what I am attempting to accomplish. I prefer altair for allowing the audience to filter the plot by security (AAPL, F, ED), as well as zoom and pan throughout the visualization.

The problem I have encountered is that data is not making it into my altair plot. Presently, I have an empty 0.7kB plot. I am at a loss.

```
import altair as alt
from altair_data_server import data_server
alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()
alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')

scatter = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    x = "RSI",
    y = "Return",
    color = "Security"
).properties(
    width=480,
    height=480
).interactive()
scatter
```

Perhaps someone with more altair know-how than myself will recognize a simple solution. If this use-case can be better addressed by a different implementation, I am very open to suggestions.

First Edit: I have abandoned using the data_server. Chart is now printing but clearly not reflecting data. Please view Colab for updates. Also, I have attempted to alter the axes to no avail.

[Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gRYIp8Lq67Vp0JiyPE4n87DWRMza_CnQ?usp=sharing)

[Altair Documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#display-troubleshooting)

[Sketch Plot using matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9sIV.png)

[Current Plot using altair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV7FL.png)

[image: Small Data Subset]

Comment: If you are trying to save the chart to a file, it will not work with `data_server` since that requires an active python kernel. It should work in a jupyter notebook however. I don't use collab, so not sure if there are any limitation with large data on that platform

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue wit ha smaller dataset that you can post here

Comment: Hi @joelostblom, I have implemented a small subset of the data with ~50 points that seems to be working. I will attach an image to the main post. It seems my efforts to configure my axes and scale have failed.

Comment: I have moved my project from Colab to a local Jupyter Notebook and my issues have resolved. If someone is aware of a data limit, dependency or other reason this would occur, I would happily accept that as an answer for this question.